# What URL will Google index when affiliate URLs first 302 redirect and then have a canonical?

Tags: google, canonical-url, rel-canonical, 302-redirect, affiliate

Look please at this setup:

- There is a main vendor on the main domain, `https://example.com`.
- There are different (many) affiliates, having own subdomains, `sub1.example.com`, `sub2.example.com`,
- Affiliate subdomains are redirected with 302! to their according subfolders, `https://example.com/sub1/`, `https://example.com/sub2/`,
- Subfolders are canonicalized to the main vendor site, like `https://example.com/sub1/` has `rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/"`.

Will Google display only the main vendor page, `https://example.com`, in search results? Or will Google still display subdomains, because of 302?

**PS**: the cause of this setup is related to the internal vendor's politics of relation with affiliates and vice versa. If you want, I would explain it, but it would make a long thread.